# Capturing the customers email from Stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Perhaps I have this wrong but looking at the documentation I expect the customers email address to be returned as receipt_email, this information is asked for when paying but it is not currently logged in the DB, there is a DB column for it.

Here is the code to create a Charge.

```
def do_transaction(self, token, price, amount, address):
    charge  = self.stripe_charge(token, price, amount)
    txid    = coin.sendtoaddress(address, amount)
    ret     = db.insert('transactions', txid=txid, price=price,
                        amount=amount, address=address, ip=df.ctx['ip'],
                        charge_id=charge.id)

    self.stripe_finish(charge)
    return ret


def stripe_charge(self, token, price, amount):
    return stripe.Charge.create(
        amount=int(price * 100), currency='usd', card=token,
        capture=False, description='%f ArtBytes' % amount)
```

The Charge id is accessible with charge.id so I hoped to get the email with email=charge.receipt_email as below but nothing is returned. No destination is set for the charge and it could be that is required for receipt_email to be valid.

```
db.insert('transactions', txid=txid, price=price, amount=amount, 
address=address, email=charge.receipt_email, ip=df.ctx['ip'], charge_id=charge.id)
```

Can I get the customers email from the charge object or should I get it another way?

API Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=python#retrieve_charge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Stripe to send an [email receipt](https://stripe.com/docs/dashboard/receipts), one of the following conditions must be met:

- you [created the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) with a customer ID in the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-customer) parameter, AND this [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) has a valid email address in its [`email`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-email) attribute, AND you've checked the "Email customers for successful payments" box in your [account settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/emails)
- you [created the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) with a valid email address in the [`receipt_email`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-receipt_email) parameter

From the code you shared, neither condition is met (your charge creation request parameters do not include either a `customer` or a `receipt_email` parameter), so Stripe has no way of knowing the customer's email address and sending a receipt.

Comment: We'll create a Customer object to store details as part of the process. Now if we can only stop these stolen credit cards!